# Google Youtube Data API - APIkey vs OAUTH

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any difference between both method features? For Example I can search using API key and find upload through OAUTH authentication?

If I can use any authentication methodology for using any feature then where can I find the code samples for api key method. Not Only Search

Comment: Also which is the preferable method?

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a huge difference between.

Which workflow to choose depends heavily on your application's requirements. When only reading data that's publicly available, an API key is sufficient. It allows you to authenticate yourself as the owner of that particular application against the API.

When accessing private user data (e.g. channel metrics, private videos) or whenever write-access to a channel is needed (e.g. uploading videos, managing playlists), then an application needs to prove that it is actually allowed to perform the requested operation. This is where OAuth comes into play:

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner [...], or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.

Quote from the [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

In other words, OAuth enables an end-user (e.g. in this case a channel owner) to delegate certain powers over his/her resources (=YouTube channel) to the application. These "powers" are defined as [scopes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#identify-access-scopes).

Also, both workflows come in server-side and client-side flavors.

To answer your question, both workflows have their own specific use cases and you cannot use them interchangeably. So there is no "preferred method" for doing stuff, it depends on what you're doing.

The best place to learn what you can do with the YouTube Data API is [its official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/). It's also full of examples for different platforms. Actions that require OAuth authentication are always marked as such:

> **Note:** This method requires user authorization.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between them two is that with API key token you can do only READ ONLY. If you want to upload the file, then you need OAUTH.

Here you have examples how to use youtube API: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples